# Will this left join on same table ever return data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, on a re-engineering project, I'm walking through some old sprocs, and I've come across this bit. I've hopefully captured the essence in this example:

### Example Table

```
SELECT * FROM People

Id | Name
-------------------------
1  | Bob Slydell
2  | Jim Halpert
3  | Pamela Landy
4  | Bob Wiley
5  | Jim Hawkins
```

### Example Query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name
    FROM People
    WHERE Id > 3
) a
LEFT JOIN People b
ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

Please disregard formatting, style, and query efficiency issues here. This example is merely an attempt to capture the exact essence of the real query I'm working with.

After looking over the real, more complex version of the query, I burned it down to this above, and I cannot for the life of me see how it would ever return any data. The `LEFT JOIN` should always exclude everything that was just selected because of the `b.Name IS NULL` check, right? (and it being the same table). If a row from People was found where b.Name IS NULL evals to true, then shouldn't that mean that data found in `People a` was never found? (impossible?)

Just to be very clear, I'm not looking for a "solution". The code is what it is. I'm merely trying to understand its behavior for the purpose of re-engineering it.

If this code indeed never returns results, then I'll conclude it was written incorrectly and use that knowledge during the re-engineering.

If there is a valid data scenario where it would/could return results, then that will be news to me and I'll have to go back to the books on SQL Joins! #DrivenCrazy

Comment: the derived table will always return 1 row.. is this correct?

Comment: In the full code, it could return multiple rows. So it could be written WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3) or similar.

Comment: What if there were rows where the name field itself was null? Though on second thoughts i don't think that would return either as then the join condition wouldn't be met.

Comment: Great question @SteveLovell. I checked and the columns are nullable, however, the results of this query are INNER JOIN'ed with another table, with the join logic being `WHERE a.Name = c.Name`. Thus the only way any dataset would result would be that rows in c would have c.Name IS NULL eval to true. Coming from the full query, I don't see this happening, nor would the resulting data be useful (the particular columns are necessary -- from a code perspective -- the table is not designed well, especially to determine intent). Good thought tho! I tracked it down just to verify.

Comment: @ryancdotnet,What is expected output..?

Comment: @Mansoor At this point I cannot make assumptions about the intended output. I can only observe what was written, and assume from there. Knowing that there is a data scenario in which this query works or not will tell me a lot. I've updated my question with some further details.

Comment: You might want to make an [sqlfiddle](sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: I see an answer has been accepted since i was here last. I'm not sure it makes any functional difference but the analysis by which you reach any conclusions here may be affected by your setting for ANSI NULLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are circumstances where this query will retrieve rows.

The query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, PName
    FROM People
    WHERE Id > 3
) a
LEFT JOIN People b
ON a.PName = b.PName
WHERE b.PName IS NULL;
```

is roughly (maybe even exactly) equivalent to...

```
select distinct Id, PName
from People
where Id > 3 and PName is null;
```

**Why?**

Tested it using this code (mysql).

```
create table People (Id int, PName varchar(50));

insert into People (Id, Pname)
  values (1, 'Bob Slydell'),
  (2, 'Jim Halpert'), 
  (3,'Pamela Landy'),
  (4,'Bob Wiley'),
  (5,'Jim Hawkins');

insert into People (Id, PName) values (6,null);
```

Now run the query. You get

```
6, Null
```

I don't know if your schema allows null Name.

What value can P.Name have such that a.PName = b.PName finds no match and b.PName is Null?

Well it's written right there. b.PName is Null.

**Can we prove that there is no other case where a row is returned?**

*Suppose there is a value for (Id,PName) such that PName is not null and a row is returned.*

1. In order to satisfy the condition...

   where b.PName is null

   ...such a value must include a PName that does not match any PName in the People table.
2. All a.PName and all b.PName values are drawn from People.PName ...
3. So a.PName may not match itself.
4. The only scalar value in SQL that does not equal itself is Null.

Therefore if there are no rows with Null PName this query will not return a row.

That's my proposed casual proof.

This is very confusing code. So #DrivenCrazy is appropriate.

Comment: Oh, I see from your comments that you intended this only to be answered with respect to the sample data provided. So the fun thing would be to prove that it can only ever return values in this case.

Comment: Thanks @joshp, this is good feedback. I agree, the query could be simplified if that was it's original intent. And yes, I am looking to see if a non-null scenario would provide data results. From my research in the real code/data, null's would not exist for these important columns. But I like your logical remarks on the possibility of null data, which may be helpful for someone looking for that side of the coin.

Comment: Do you think, without having null in the data, there could be results from the example query? If you can explain it, yes or no, either way, in your answer, then I might be able to accept your answer :) I'm looking for a similar logic breakdown that you did with the null data scenario. This is more about me confirming/denying my understanding of how the example code is functioning. #HelpPutMyMindAtEase or #TeachMeSomethingNew #LateNightCoding

Comment: @ryancdotnet I tried with a pseudo-proof in the answer. I do not believe it can return any rows for the sample data, at least not without using the Dark Side of The Force.

Comment: @ryancdotnet & joshp Don't forget the DISTINCT. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the query is exactly "return people with id > 3 and a null as name", i.e. it may return data but only if there are null-values in the name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, PName
FROM People
WHERE Id > 3 and PName is null
```

The proof for this is rather simple, if we consider the meaning of the left join condition `... LEFT JOIN People b ON a.PName = b.PName` together with the (overall) condition `where p.pname is null`:

Generally, a condition `where PName = PName` is true if and only if `PName` is not null, and it has exactly the same meaning as `where PName is not null`. Hence, the left join will match only tuples where `pname is not null`, but any matching row will subsequently be filtered out by the overall condition `where pname is null`.

Hence, the left join cannot introduce any new rows in the query, and it cannot reduce the set of rows of the left hand side (as a left join never does). So the left join is superfluous, and the only effective condition is `where PName is null`.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN ON returns the rows that INNER JOIN ON returns plus unmatched rows of the left table extended by NULL for the right table columns. If the ON condition does not allow a matched row to have NULL in some column (like `b.NAME` here being equal to something) then the only NULLs in that column in the result are from unmatched left hand rows. So keeping rows with NULL for that column as the result gives exactly the rows unmatched by the INNER JOIN ON. (This is an idiom. In some cases it can also be expressed via NOT IN or EXCEPT.)

In your case the left table has distinct People rows with `a.Id > 3` and the right table has all People rows. So the only `a` rows unmatched in `a.Name = b.Name` are those where `a.Name IS NULL`. So the WHERE returns those rows extended by NULLs.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM People WHERE Id > 3 AND Name IS NULL) a
LEFT JOIN People b ON 1=0;
```

But then you `SELECT a.*`. So the entire query is just

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM People WHERE Id > 3 AND Name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

sure.left join will return data even if the join is done on the same table.
according to your query

```
 "SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name
    FROM People
    WHERE Id > 3
) a
LEFT JOIN People b
ON a.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Name IS NULL"
```

it returns null because of the final filtering `"b.Name IS NULL"`.without that filtering it will return `2 records with id > 3`

Comment: Thanks, that is the behavior I see as well when the `b.Name IS NULL` where clause is removed. But what I'm really asking is will data ever be returned while leaving the where clause intact? (Apart from the scenario of a Name being NULL-- which is not in my example table on purpose as that is not expected in the real dataset).